# Text editors not functional

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, bash

Running into a slightly strange situation. Basically for reasons outside of my control I'm on a server that somebody else has set up. I've got sudo access, I just can't figure out what happened or find any documentation.

When I open `.bashrc` (`sudo nano ~/.bashrc`) I get a static view that just overwrites the top row. I can exit only by hitting `enter` after hitting `Ctrl+X`. Screenshot below.

[image]

Same thing happens with `vi`, and obviously this makes it impossible to edit anything on the server. Anyone have an idea as to what might be happening here? I've done a lot of googling, but it's tough to lock this down.

Response of `lsb_release -a` pasted below.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Looking for any weird code lying around I found the following in the `.bashrc`:

```
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

I'm not certain what's going on here tbh, but it was the only thing that I didn't recognize so it might be related?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like someone has messed with the (virtual) tty settings that are best left alone in the 21st century, unless of course you're actually using an antique physical terminal from a computer museum...

You should be able to get the tty on the remote server into a usable state with the command (run on the remote server, immediately after logging in):

```
stty sane
```

After you've got the terminal working, look for commands like `stty` or `tput` in the shell startup scripts which might be doing strange things to the tty.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately that didn't change anything.

Comment: @SlaterVictoroff Probably time to start looking at your local terminal, then.

Comment: Same local terminal works fine sshing into other remote envs. Anything else you'd suggest I check? Is stty sane supposed to give some kind of output?

Comment: I found something weird in the `.bashrc` but not sure it's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the bottom of the file the next line:

```
export EDITOR=/path/vi
```

> path= The location of the vi editor.

You can execute the command in your current terminal before editing .bashrc.

Comment: This wasn't the issue

Answer (score 0):

You imply, this happens to any file you try to edit.

I think the bashrc seems ok, I have seen similar code in https://gist.github.com/aakbar5/2969095d8dd11e95a282157c2ca29b39, and it’s explained why that case statement is there.

If you think replacing the bashrc help, you can edit a file without an editor. Make a back up first. This uses Here Doc.

```
cat > ~/.bashrc <‘HT’
# replacement goes here

HT
```

As for the text editors, what are the path of each? i.e., what is the output of `which vi`?

Answer (score 0):

Try running editor of your preference in `screen` session.
This helps me with such problems 99% of the time. I also believe that this is a problem with TTY setting / some Xterm variables, you could try exporting `env` output from another machine and sourcing such file on this one checking if that solves the problem the proper way, but I would use `screen` first